# Please Explain: $-\sqrt{x}(3x^2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$-\sqrt{x}(3x^2)$

My book tells me that this will equal $-6x^3$ Can someone explain why?

I would think that this equals $-3x^{3/2}$

Comment: It's neither nor, but $-3x^{5/2}$

Answer (score 2):

$$-\sqrt{x}(3x^2) = -x^{\frac{1}{2}}3x^2 = -3x^{\frac{1}{2}+2} = -3x^{\frac{5}{2}}$$

Comment: When adding 2 to the exponent.  Why do you get a common denominator in this case.  I was always under the impression that with exponents this is not necessary.  However that does appear to be the other correct answer.

Comment: That is because $2$ can be written as $\frac{4}{2}$

Comment: If it doesn't appear to be the right answer, then the question you have posted is definitely wrong.

Comment: I see that 2 can be written as 4/2 my quesiton is why do we choose in this case to write it as such?

In most cases with exponents we just add across 1/2+2/1=3/2

Comment: You must go through your books again as your basics are seriously wrong. $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{1}$ is never equal to $\frac{3}{2}$

Answer (score 2):

$- \sqrt{x}(3x^2) = -3x^{\frac{5}{2}} \neq -6x^3$. Perhaps your book weren't saying that they were equal, but instead wanted you to solve for $x$?

Comment: Nah It is a part of a derivative I am trying to solve

Comment: What was the question as stated in the book?

Comment: Use the quotient rule to differentiate the function:

sqrt(x)/(x^(3)+1)

Comment: $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^3 + 1}$? Did you perhaps mean $\sqrt{x} (x^3 + 1)$? If so, I see where you made your mistake (although the derivative of that is not equal to $-6x^3$, either).